# Long build time in Gulp (Docker)

Tags: node.js, docker, webpack, gulp

My build time with Gulp is around 90 seconds (occasionally even more), which seems extremely slow build time. I'm using Django, Tailwindcss, Gulp, Webpack, and Docker. I tried 'npm run dev' without docker and it took 41 seconds.

How can I optimize my Gulp configurations when using Docker?

```sh
node_1      | ✔ - [Styles] Success!
node_1      | [12:40:43] Finished 'styles' after 49 s
node_1      | [12:40:48] asset index.js 138 KiB [emitted] (name: main) 1 related asset
node_1      |   
node_1      | webpack 5.51.1 compiled successfully
node_1      | ✔ - [Scripts] Success!
node_1      | [12:40:49] Finished 'scripts' after 54 s
node_1      | ✔ - [HTML] Success!
node_1      | [12:40:54] Finished 'html' after 59 s
node_1      | [12:41:10] gulp-imagemin: Minified 1 image (saved 11 B - 0.1%)
node_1      | ✔ - [Images] Success!
node_1      | [12:41:10] Finished 'images' after 1.25 min
node_1      | [12:41:10] Finished 'build' after 1.27 min
node_1      | [12:41:17] Using gulpfile /usr/src/app/gulpfile.mjs
node_1      | [12:41:17] Starting 'watch'...
node_1      | [Browsersync] Proxying: http://localhost:8000
node_1      | [Browsersync] Access URLs:
node_1      |  -----------------------------------
node_1      |        Local: http://localhost:8000
node_1      |     External: http://172.18.0.4:8000
node_1      |  -----------------------------------
node_1      |           UI: http://localhost:3001
node_1      |  UI External: http://localhost:3001
node_1      |  -----------------------------------
node_1      | [Browsersync] Watching files...
```

#### gulpfile

```js
/* eslint-disable import/newline-after-import */

import figures from 'figures';
import imagemin, { gifsicle, mozjpeg, optipng, svgo } from 'gulp-imagemin';

import { createRequire } from 'module';
const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);
// "require" is not defined with ES6 module, so we define it this way above.
// Now 'require' can be used in the usual way.
// Use import for ES6 modules and require for commonJS.

const gulp = require('gulp');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
const gulpAutoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
const gulpClean = require('gulp-clean');
const gulpColor = require('gulp-color');
const gulpConcat = require('gulp-concat');
const gulpCssnano = require('gulp-cssnano');
const htmlMinimizer = require('gulp-html-minimizer'); // Minify HTML files
const gulpPostcss = require('gulp-postcss');
const gulpSass = require('gulp-sass')(require('sass'));
const gulpSourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
const gulpUtil = require('gulp-util');
const purgeCss = require('@fullhuman/postcss-purgecss');
const tailwindCSS = require('tailwindcss');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const webpackStream = require('webpack-stream');

const isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';
const webpackConfig = isProd
  ? require('./webpack.config.prod')
  : require('./webpack.config');

// Config
const options = {
  config: {
    tailwindjs: './tailwind.config.js',
  },
  paths: {
    src: {
      base: './assets',
      html: './templates/local',
      css: './assets/css',
      js: './assets/js',
      img: './assets/img',
    },
    dist: {
      base: './dist',
      html: './templates/local',
      css: './dist/css',
      js: './dist/js',
      img: './dist/img',
    },
    build: {
      base: './config/static',
      html: './templates/production',
      css: './config/static/css',
      js: './config/static/js',
      img: './config/static/img',
    },
  },
};

const logger = (text, symbol = figures.info, color = 'YELLOW') => {
  console.log(gulpColor(`${symbol} - ${text}`, color));
};
const reload = done => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    browserSync.reload();
  }, 1000);
  done();
};

gulp.task('clean', () => {
  logger('[Cleaning] Cleaning old dist..');
  return gulp
    .src(
      isProd
        ? [options.paths.build.base, options.paths.build.html]
        : options.paths.dist.base,
      {
        read: false,
        allowEmpty: true,
      }
    )
    .pipe(gulpClean())
    .on('end', () => logger('[Cleaning] Success!', figures.tick, 'GREEN'))
    .on('error', () => logger('[Cleaning] Failed', figures.cross, 'RED'));
});

// Updated gulp pipe: passing webpack in webpack-stream to avoid this issue:
// https://github.com/webpack-contrib/terser-webpack-plugin/issues/335
gulp.task('scripts', () => {
  logger('[Scripts] Compiling...');
  return gulp
    .src(`${options.paths.src.js}/app.js`)
    .pipe(webpackStream(webpackConfig, webpack))
    .pipe(
      isProd
        ? gulp.dest(options.paths.build.js)
        : gulp.dest(options.paths.dist.js)
    )
    .on('end', () => logger('[Scripts] Success!', figures.tick, 'GREEN'))
    .on('error', () => logger('[Scripts] Failed', figures.cross, 'RED'));
});

gulp.task('styles', () => {
  logger('[Styles] Compiling...');
  return gulp
    .src(`${options.paths.src.css}/**/*.scss`)
    .pipe(gulpSass().on('error', gulpSass.logError))
    .pipe(
      gulpPostcss([
        tailwindCSS(options.config.tailwindjs),
        autoprefixer,
        ...(isProd
          ? [
              purgeCss({
                content: [
                  `${options.paths.src.html}/**/*.{html}`,
                  `${options.paths.src.js}/**/*.{js}`,
                ],
                defaultExtractor: content => {
                  const broadMatches =
                    content.match(/[^<>"'`\s]*[^<>"'`\s:]/g) || [];
                  const innerMatches =
                    content.match(/[^<>"'`\s.()]*[^<>"'`\s.():]/g) || [];
                  return broadMatches.concat(innerMatches);
                },
              }),
            ]
          : []),
      ])
    )
    .pipe(gulpAutoprefixer())
    .pipe(isProd ? gulpSourcemaps.init() : gulpUtil.noop())
    .pipe(gulpConcat('style.css'))
    .pipe(isProd ? gulpCssnano() : gulpUtil.noop())
    .pipe(isProd ? gulpSourcemaps.write('.') : gulpUtil.noop())
    .pipe(
      isProd
        ? gulp.dest(options.paths.build.css)
        : gulp.dest(options.paths.dist.css)
    )
    .on('end', () => logger('[Styles] Success!', figures.tick, 'GREEN'))
    .on('error', () => logger('[Styles] Failed', figures.cross, 'RED'));
});

gulp.task('images', () => {
  logger('[Images] Optimizing...');
  return gulp
    .src(`${options.paths.src.img}/**/*.*`)
    .pipe(
      imagemin(
        [
          gifsicle({ interlaced: true }),
          mozjpeg({
            quality: 80,
            progressive: true,
          }),
          optipng({ optimizationLevel: 5 }),
          svgo({ removeViewBox: true, cleanupIDs: false }),
        ],
        {
          silent: false,
        }
      )
    )
    .pipe(
      isProd
        ? gulp.dest(options.paths.build.img)
        : gulp.dest(options.paths.dist.img)
    )
    .on('end', () => logger('[Images] Success!', figures.tick, 'GREEN'))
    .on('error', () => logger('[Images] Failed', figures.cross, 'RED'));
});

gulp.task('html', () => {
  logger('[HTML] Optimizing...');
  return gulp
    .src(`${options.paths.src.html}/**/*.html`)
    .pipe(
      isProd
        ? htmlMinimizer({
            collapseWhitespace: true,
            removeComments: true,
            continueOnParseError: true,
            html5: true,
            // minifyJS: true,
            // minifyCSS: true,
          })
        : gulpUtil.noop()
    )
    .pipe(
      isProd
        ? gulp.dest(options.paths.build.html)
        : gulp.dest(options.paths.dist.html)
    )
    .on('end', () => logger('[HTML] Success!', figures.tick, 'GREEN'))
    .on('error', () => logger('[HTML] Failed', figures.cross, 'RED'));
});

gulp.task('watch', () => {
  browserSync.init({
    // The hostname is the name of your service in docker-compose.yml.
    // The port is what's defined in your Dockerfile.
    hostname: 'django',
    port: 8000,
    proxy: 'localhost:8000',
    open: false,
    files: ['./dist', './templates/local'],
  });

  gulp
    .watch(`${options.paths.src.js}/**/*.*`, gulp.series('scripts'))
    .on('change', reload);
  gulp
    .watch(`${options.paths.src.css}/**/*.*`, gulp.series('styles'))
    .on('change', reload);
  gulp
    .watch(`${options.paths.src.img}/**/*.*`, gulp.series('images'))
    .on('change', reload);
  gulp
    .watch(`${options.paths.src.html}/**/*.*`, gulp.series('html'))
    .on('change', reload);
});

gulp.task(
  'build',
  gulp.series('clean', gulp.parallel('scripts', 'styles', 'images', 'html'))
);
```

#### webpack.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: ['./assets/js/app.js'],
  output: {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-path-concat
    path: `${__dirname}/dist/js`,
    filename: 'index.js',
  },
  devtool: false,
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        resolve: {
          fullySpecified: false,
        },
        exclude: /node_modules\/(?!app-js)/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

#### Dockerfile

```sh
FROM node:12.22-buster-slim

RUN npm i npm@latest -g

WORKDIR /usr/src

COPY ./app/package*.json ./

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    autoconf \
    automake \
    g++ \
    libpng-dev \
    make\
    nasm \
    -y wget \
    && wget -q -O /tmp/libpng12.deb http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/libp/libpng/libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb \
    && dpkg -i /tmp/libpng12.deb \
    && rm /tmp/libpng12.deb \
    && npm install --no-optional && npm cache clean --force \
    npm install -g gulp \
    && npm install gulp

ENV PATH /usr/src/node_modules/.bin/:$PATH

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY . .
```

#### docker-compose.yml

```sh
version: '3'

volumes:
  local_postgres_data: {}
  local_postgres_data_backups: {}
  notused:

services:
  postgres:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./app/docker/postgres/Dockerfile
    image: webapp_prodcution_postgres
    volumes:
      - local_postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:Z
      - local_postgres_data_backups:/backups:z
    env_file:
      - ./app/.envs/.local/.env

  django:
    image: webapp_local_django
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./app/docker/django/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./app/:/usr/src/app/
    command: /usr/src/app/docker/django/start_dev
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    env_file:
      - ./app/.envs/.local/.env
    depends_on:
      - postgres

  node:
    image: webapp_local_node
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./app/docker/node/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - django
    volumes:
      - ./app/:/usr/src/app/
      - notused:/usr/src/app/node_modules/
    command: bash -c "rm -rf /usr/src/app/node_modules/* && npm run dev"
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
```

#### package.json

```js
{
  "private": true,
  "main": "gulpfile.mjs",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "gulp build && gulp watch",
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production gulp build",
    "preinstall": "npx npm-force-resolutions"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.15.0",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.15.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.15.0",
    "@fullhuman/postcss-purgecss": "^4.0.3",
    "@tailwindcss/aspect-ratio": "^0.2.1",
    "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.3.3",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.3.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "browser-sync": "^2.27.5",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^14.2.1",
    "eslint-config-node": "^4.1.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.24.0",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.4.0",
    "figures": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^8.0.0",
    "gulp-babel": "^8.0.0",
    "gulp-clean": "^0.4.0",
    "gulp-cli": "^2.3.0",
    "gulp-color": "0.0.2",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
    "gulp-cssnano": "^2.1.3",
    "gulp-html-minimizer": "^2.0.1",
    "gulp-imagemin": "^8.0.0",
    "gulp-postcss": "^9.0.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^5.0.0",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.8",
    "postcss": "^8.3.6",
    "prettier": "^2.3.2",
    "sass": "^1.37.5",
    "tailwindcss": "^2.2.7",
    "webpack": "^5.50.0",
    "webpack-stream": "^6.1.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "alpinejs": "^3.2.4",
    "aos": "^3.0.0-beta.6",
    "focus-handling": "^1.0.0",
    "sticky-js": "^1.3.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=12.22"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "glob-parent": "6.0.1",
    "trim-newlines": "4.0.2",
    "yargs-parser": "20.2.9",
    "js-yaml": "4.1.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: can you show how does your Dockerfile looks like?

Comment: @Stefano I updated my question and added more information regarding Docker.

Answer (score 1):

From the docker point of view, you can improve how the cache is being used. I don't think what you posted is complete, anyway I'll use what's available.

I'd rewrite it this way:

```
FROM node:12.22-buster-slim

RUN npm i npm@latest -g \
    && npm install -g gulp

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    autoconf \
    automake \
    g++ \
    libpng-dev \
    make\
    nasm \
    -y wget \
    && wget -q -O /tmp/libpng12.deb http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/libp/libpng/libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb \
    && dpkg -i /tmp/libpng12.deb \
    && rm /tmp/libpng12.deb

WORKDIR /usr/src

COPY ./app/package*.json ./

RUN npm ci

ENV PATH /usr/src/node_modules/.bin/:$PATH

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY . .
```

The next step would be to improve on the package.json file and add a couple of scripts to avoid installing gulp multiple times. (I'm assuming that the reason you're doing it is because the docker container cannot find it if it's installed only in the project).

Comment: Thank you! I also added my package.json. Could you please check it out?